# How to convert pandas dataframe columns to native python data types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe whose columns data types need to be mapped to python native data types.

I want to be able to get a dictionary from numpy and convert each column to it's native type.

for example:

```
{numpy.object_: object,
 numpy.bool_: bool,
 numpy.string_: str,
 numpy.unicode_: unicode,
 numpy.int64: int,
 numpy.float64: float,
 numpy.complex128: complex}
```

I tried both `astype` and `pd.to_numeric`,  neither downcasts the column sufficiently.

`df['source'] = df['source'].astype(int)` returns `int32`, as does `pd.to_numeric`

#### Update:

Most of the comments question the wisdom for doing this. `networkx` reads `dataframes` and accepts `np datatypes`. However the graph cannot be written  using `json_dumps` because of this well documented error: `TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable`

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't. Why would you? It's much faster to process them as numpy types.

Comment: With a `numpy` array, `tolist()` or `item()` (for one element) is the best way of getting either a list or native Python object.  `astype` just changes the array `dtype`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Native Python type" to pandas (or to numpy) is an object. That's the extent of it. Pandas only knows it's a Python object and act accordingly. Other than that, you cannot have columns of type string, unicode, integers etc.

You can have object columns and store whatever you want inside them, though. Pandas will handle most of the conversion for you at this stage.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 
                   'B': [1., 2.], 
                   'C': [1 + 2j, 3 + 4j], 
                   'D': [True, False], 
                   'E': ['a', 'b'], 
                   'F': [b'a', b'b']})

df.dtypes
Out[71]: 
A         int64
B       float64
C    complex128
D          bool
E        object
F        object
dtype: object

for col in df:
    print(type(df.loc[0, col]))

<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.complex128'>
<class 'numpy.bool_'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
```

---

```
df = df.astype('object')

for col in df:
    print(type(df.loc[0, col]))

<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'complex'>
<class 'bool'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas and by extension Dataframes are built on numpy so you do not get to choose the specific type which is stored. Your best bet is to use [to_dict](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and then use that as a poor-mans dataframe. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Use numpy tolist

```
(getattr(x, "tolist", lambda: x)() for x in df)
```

See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html