# psycopg2: can't adapt type 'numpy.int64'

Tags: numpy, psycopg2

I have a dataframe with the dtypes shown below and I want to insert the dataframe into a postgres DB but it fails due to error ***can't adapt type 'numpy.int64'***

```
id_code               int64
sector              object
created_date         float64
updated_date    float64
```

How can I convert these types to native python types such as from int64 (which is essentially 'numpy.int64') to a classic int that would then be acceptable to postgres via the psycopg2 client.

```
data['id_code'].astype(np.int)  defaults to int64
```

It is nonetheless possible to convert from one numpy type to another (e.g from int to float)

```
data['id_code'].astype(float)
```

changes to

```
dtype: float64
```

The bottomline is that psycopg2 doesn't seem to understand numpy datatypes if any one has ideas how to convert them to classic types that would be helpful.

Updated: Insertion to DB

```
def insert_many():
    """Add data to the table."""
    sql_query = """INSERT INTO classification(
                id_code, sector, created_date, updated_date)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"""
    data = pd.read_excel(fh, sheet_name=sheetname)
    data_list = list(data.to_records())

    conn = None
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(db)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.executemany(sql_query, data_list)
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
    except(Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you do the insert?

Comment: @Michael sure, updated description of the issue.

Comment: Have you tried defining id_code as a BIGINT?

Comment: If you mean defining it as BIGINT on the DB side, no I did not try that approach since I understood the issue to be the psycopg2 client not being  to map numpy types to python natives.

Comment: Ints come back out of a DataFrame as numpy.int64.
`data = [[1],[2]]`
`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`
`print(type(df.iloc[0][0]))`

results in <class 'numpy.int64'>

Comment: also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423930/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-columns-to-native-python-data-types).

`data['id_code'].astype('object')` will write directly to postgres in my use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why your data_list contains NumPy data types, but the same thing happens to me when I run your code. Here is an alternative way to construct data_list that so that integers and floats end up as their native python types:

```
data_list = [list(row) for row in data.itertuples(index=False)]
```

---

**Alternate approach**

I think you could accomplish the same thing in fewer lines of code by using pandas [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(fh, sheet_name=sheetname)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql://username@hostname/dbname")
data.to_sql(engine, 'classification', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: In my environment, generating the list using a comprehension still results in numpy data types:                                                                        `In [341]: type([list(row) for row in data.itertuples(index=False)][0][0])
Out[341]: numpy.int64
`

Comment: Actually noted that the data_list generated from the comprehension as suggested is parsed withouth any issues by pyscopg2 despite the numpy data types.

Answer (score 28):

**Update:**

If the value includes `NaN`, it still wrong.
It seems that `psycopg2` can't explain the `np.int64` format, the following method works for me.

```
import numpy as np
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, AsIs
register_adapter(np.int64, AsIs)
```

Original answer:

same problem here, successfully solve this problem after I transform series to nd.array and int.

you can try as following:

```
data['id_code'].values.astype(int)
```

--

Comment: Thanks, `register_adapter` helped.  Note that with those imports, fully-qualified references don't work, you want just:

`register_adapter(np.int64, AsIs)`

Comment: Thank you, this fixed `ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'numpy.int64'`

Answer (score 25):

Add below somewhere in your code:

```
import numpy
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, AsIs
def addapt_numpy_float64(numpy_float64):
    return AsIs(numpy_float64)
def addapt_numpy_int64(numpy_int64):
    return AsIs(numpy_int64)
register_adapter(numpy.float64, addapt_numpy_float64)
register_adapter(numpy.int64, addapt_numpy_int64)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and fixed it using:
`df = df.convert_dtypes()`